# Unable to update the EntitySet '' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <DeleteFunction>

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

The entire error message is below:

Unable to update the EntitySet '' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation.

So everything I've read is talking about not having a Primary Key. However I have a primary key. I have a composite primary key of a couple fields. Is it not possible to delete a record with entity framework with a composite primary key on the table? If this is the case it seems silly to add 1 field just for this purpose. What are my other options?

Here is what I'm doing (an example)

```
var recs = (from a in dbContext.mytable where a.State == 'Texas' select a);

foreach(var d in recs)
{
   dbContext.myTable.Remove(d);
}

dbContext.SaveChanges(); // ERROR
```

Imagine that mytable has 10 fields and 4 or them make up the PK.

Comment: Everything? What about database views? Please give some more background information.

Comment: What about views? This is a table that I'm working with. I can't think of any more info to give. I have a table that has a composite primary key. I try to delete records from it by looping over the results of a linq query on the table and calling context.Table.Remove(rec); and it gives me this error when I call SaveChanges(). That's all there is.

Comment: Screw it, I just used ExecuteStoreCommand() and got it working.

Comment: Well, yes, executing raw SQL will do anything you like. Still your code looks like it should work, but it's hard to deduce what's wrong with these tiny bits of information.

Comment: If you have a defining query it means that the entity set is not mapped to an actual table but is built based on a query that is stored in the edmx.